# Spring boot picking @value from default properties file

Tags: spring-boot

I am using @value annotation in spring boot to read a property

```
@Value(value = "${propName:#{null}}")
private String prop;
```

And based on if it is null or driving some logic in my code. In my dev environment I want to keep it null so I don't add it in that property file (application-dev.properties). But instead of getting it as null, it is reading the value from default application.properties file.

Comment: make sure that your dev profile is active.
You can explicitly set it using -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the correct behavior based on Spring's property resolution.  If you want to override it in your `dev` profile, simply add the property to your `application-dev.properties`, leaving the value empty.  This will result in an empty String, not null, which you can convert to null with something like this:

```
@Value("${#{some_property == \"\"}:#{null}}")
private String prop;
```

It is probably a good idea to explicitly define these properties and give them values that make sense.  Otherwise, you'll likely revisit this code in a few months and wonder what the heck is causing `xyz`.

You can read up on Spring and the order with which it resolves properties [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) but generally, you'd want to define variables that apply to all environments in your `application.[properties][yaml]`, and then override them in the environment-specific properties files.  In this case, it kind of sounds like this is a flag that's on or off depending on if the dev environment is set; you might consider something like this.

```
@Value("${property_to_drive_behavior:false}"
private Boolean prop;
```

This will default to false, so you don't need to add it to any properties file.  If you want it set, override it in the environment-specific properties file.  Booleans can be set in properties files using either the explicit `true` or `false` keywords or the values or `0` for false, `1` for true.

Answer (score 0):

By default, property values of external configuration sources (such as `application.properties` files) are always injected directly into your beans by using the `@Value` annotation.

One solution to your problem is moving the `propName` property from `application.properties` to `application-{profile}.properties`.